# Android app does not start when file provider added to manifest

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

**This is my manifest file**

```
<application>
    <provider
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
  </application>
```

**This is my file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <root-path name="root" path="" />
  <external-path name="external_storage_root" path="." />
  <external-path name="external_storage_download" path="Download" />
</paths>
```

**When I try and execute my app I get the following errors**

> Error     failed processing manifest.          Error      resource xml/file_paths
> (aka com.companyname.ProjectName:xml/file_paths) not found.
>
> This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml
> file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code
> file. Project Name
> C:..\source\repos\ProjectName\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml

**I searched google and tried alot of solutions but non of them actually worked soo here i am now, hopefully someone can help me.**

Comment: Where are you placing your file_paths.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create a folder named `xml` in your `Resources` folder ?

like below:

[image]